# center align rotated text in a triangle

Tags: css

I have this following [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mC22Q/).

This is the HTML markup.

```html
<div id="container">
    <img id="rotate" height="80" width="80" src="http://i.imgur.com/dEM0KGG.png" />
    <span id="text">Download</span>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS too.

```css
#container {
    position:absolute;
    height:80px;
    width:80px;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:2147483647;
}

#rotate {
    position:absolute;
    height:113px;
    width:113px;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin:100% 0%;
    -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform-origin:100% 0%;
    -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform-origin:100% 0%;
    -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform-origin:100% 0%;
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    transform-origin:100% 0%;
    background:#3868D9;
    right:0px;
    z-index:9001;

}

#text {
    position:absolute;
    -webkit-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(-45deg);
    transform:rotate(-45deg);
    z-index:9001;
    top:35px;
    right:0px;
}
```

I want to place a text like how I have shown. The problem I am facing with is that the text can change dynamically and if I use the same position it doesn't display properly.

Is there any way I can position it dynamically based on the width of the text/container?
Also the width of the container can change. Right now its 80 x 80 but can be 50 x 50. How can I position it?

Comment: Why not rotating the entire element, instead of the image and text separately?

Comment: @Tzach thanks dude. i did what you said and positioned it inside a div. it comes proper.

Comment: Great. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try rotating the entire `#container` element, instead of the image and the text separately.

Answer (score 0):

you can't resize the font dynamically, what you can do is to use a little js to solve your problem!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
setInterval(function(){
    var cont=document.getElementById("container").style;
    if(cont.width!="80px"){
        document.getElementById("text").style.fontSize="9px";
        document.getElementById("text").style.top="50%";
        }
    else{
        document.getElementById("text").style.fontSize="16px";}
},1);
```

just add this code to the head tag

Comment: if by any chance it didn't work add this two lines above setInterval: document.getElementById("container").style.width="80px";
document.getElementById("container").style.height="80px";